# How do I get the initial status bar height?

Tags: ios, swift

I tried `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height`, but when I start the app with the in-call status bar enabled I get 40 instead of 20. I printed the value in my initial post in the viewDidLoad function of the initial view controller. I have a UIView positioned directly behind the status bar acting as a 'background view' to produce a custom status bar background color. When 40 is returned and the in-call status bar has disappeared, the view is far larger than it should be.

Comment: Provide more details. Where do you call this code? What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: But why do you need to know the height? If you write your app properly, you don't need to know the height.

Comment: I need to know the height because the height of the 'background view' should match the default height of the status bar.

Comment: Nevermind, I realized that it'd be easier to simply shift some of my content downward and change the background color of the parent UIView.

Answer (score 2):

Check `statusBarOrientation` first:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
```

When in portrait use this:

```
let status_height = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
```

When in landscape use this:

```
let status_height = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.width
```

Comment: In landscape mode why we are getting status bar height & width are 0